# `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Engine::Configuration:0x9d6a6d8> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `assets' for #<Rails::Engine::Configuration:0x9d6a6d8> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/font-awesome-sass-4.2.1/lib/font_awesome/sass/rails/engine.rb:10:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /var/www/device/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/www/device/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /var/www/device/config.ru:in `new'
    from /var/www/device/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

getting this error when I use rails s. then after I update the rails using rake rails:update
it shows 'wrap-parameter' error.

Comment: Have the same issue when compiling assets on production

Answer (score 2):

Version 4.2.1 of `font-awesome-sass` has a bug I've found and reported here:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/issues/58

Change your gem version to `4.2.0`

That works for me.